# Image with valid source and sizing not visible

Tags: html, css

I have downloaded a login template for a project and I am trying to add a logo to the site.

Below is the html code I'm using

```css
.logo{
  position:absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 10%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
        <title>RNL Trading intern</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/test-image.png">
    </head>
    <body >
        <div class="logo" src="icons/test-image.png" alt="rnl-logo"></div>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center light-blue-gradient" style="height: 100vh;">
            <div class="container" >
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="card rounded-0 shadow">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3>Log in</h3>
                                <form>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                                        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Wachtwoord</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group form-check">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
                <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The favicon works so the image source is valid. I wrote a little css to size up the image and position it to the top left:

This is what shows up on the page after refreshing cache:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<div class="logo" src="icons/test-image.png" alt="rnl-logo"></div>`

You can't use an `image` directly without using `img` tag.
The correct way should be :

```
    <div class="logo">
       <img class="" src="./icons/test-image.png" alt="rnl-logo">
    </div>
```

OR:

```
<img class="logo" src="./icons/test-image.png" alt="rnl-logo">
```

Reference  : [: The Image Embed element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)